# Strange overcurrent problem using two op-amps together

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, buffer

This is the circuit of the mentioned two [op-amps](https://www.richtek.com/Products/Operational%20Amplifier/RT9146RT9147?sc_lang=en&specid=RT9146/RT9147) which are basically only current buffers;

[image: IC1102]

[image: IC1103]

They are both supplied with 12 V and GND. They share the VCOM_x reference voltage as input which is around 7 V. When I ran them without any load connected to them I noticed they are thermally terrible, up to 130°:

[image: IC1102 thermal]

[image: IC1103 thermal]

It is because they are drawing 850 mA when there is no load! The source of the heat must be inside the chip somewhere, not the output transistors, because when I connect the loads (i.e. 750 Ω for a 10 mA load current) I see that the input follows the output and the op-amps can withstand 1 A. As I said, they are designed to be current buffers. So this 850 mA must be heating something inside the chip. After a while this triggers thermal shutdown and the output becomes low, then an on again, off again, situation. The bottom line is I came to notice this strange thing. Look at the configs below:

[image: conf1]

12 V supply, both A+ and B+ inputs of one buffer tied together to GND in buffer mode, it is OK!

[image: conf2]

12 V supply, both A+ and B+ inputs of one buffer tied together to 12 V in buffer mode, it is OK!

[image: conf3]

12 V same supply to each, A+ and B+ inputs of IC1103 and A+ input of IC1102 are tied together to GND, it starts heating abnormally, I saw 60° without a load.

[image: conf4]

12 V same supply to each, A+ and B+ inputs of IC1103 and A+ input of IC1102 are tied together to 12 V, it blows up the power switch transistor whose current rating is 3.9 A.

When I run the single op-amp separately, I see that the output follows the input from 0 to 12 V, but when I connect their inputs together, they will almost explode. What might be the reason for this?

Comment: According to the datasheet, the input common-mode range does not extend to the rails. You have to keep them at least 0.5V away.

Comment: @DaveTweed it is designed to supply VCOM (~7V) and HAVDD also around 7V. Also I don't think it would explain the overcurrent and thermal issue.

Comment: In your diagram you have one of the op-amps with ground disconnected is that really how it's connected?

Comment: You checked for oscillation?

Comment: Suggestion: please, for everyone's sanity, draw your schematics using standard symbols for standard parts. A square block with pins laid out to mimic the physical package makes it unnecessarily difficult for others to interpret the schematic. One of the primary purposes of a schematic is to describe the circuit to other humans - using standard symbols makes that more effective.

Comment: @VoltageSpike it is a mistake on my drawing. it is connected to GND.

Comment: @brhans I thought it would be easier. I will also add the circuitlab version to the Q.

Comment: @evildemonic there is a an unusual ripple on the outputs. I will add the measurement waveforms on monday.

Comment: @Alper91 I'm suggesting that you do this for all schematics you draw, not just those you post here. Future engineers are going to look at your schematics, and not using standard symbols for standard parts hides information from them - information which would make it easier to interpret & understand the schematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally cannot drive capacitive loads directly with high speed opamps.  I would try first removing R1165, R1184, R1194 and R1197 and see if this solves your problem.  If it doesn't you likely have a circuit error somewhere.

Next, experiment with resistor values until you find a value that reduces the no-load current draw.

Finally, remember that you are dropping 5 volts (12 -7) across the op amp.  If you run 1 amp, you will be dissipating 5 watts in the opamp.  You can see this is out of range for the part from the chart below, taken from the data sheet.

[image]

Good Luck!

Answer (score 6):

Don't leave unused op-amp inputs floating <-- connect them to 0 volts and also note this in the [data sheet](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT9146=RT9147/DS9146_47-03.pdf): -

> Connect a 0.1μF capacitor from VINx+ to ground and place it as close
> to the IC as possible for better performance